# Safety of using GDAL OpenFileGDB (reverse engineered) driver?

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, file-geodatabase-api

http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html

My understanding is that GDAL offers an alternative to accessing Geodatabase files via Esri's API SDK. Apparently Even Rouault reverse engineered the Geodatabase format, at least enough to get the basic geometry out (https://github.com/rouault/dump_gdbtable/wiki/FGDB-Spec).

It seems risky to use this (a) because perhaps the reverse engineering is imperfect (there are many "unknown"s in that spec) and maybe it could mess up on some unusual file because Even didn't understand the purpose of some field/flag, and (b) because there could be changes to the Geodatabase format at some point that the official SDK deals with correctly but the reverse engineering messes up on.

However, both of those seem fairly unlikely. And the big advantage for me of avoiding the Esri API SDK is that I don't have to integrate the libraries into my code, which is a big deal on Mac because the SDK only appears to be available in 64-bit, so will force my whole Mac build to become 64-bit, which is not something I want to deal with right now.

Does anybody have experience using the reverse engineered solution?

Comment: You analysis feels correct. There is some risk but bug reports about the openfilegdb driver https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/query?status=assigned&status=closed&status=new&status=reopened&description=~openfilegdb&order=priority does not seem to contain anything critical. Perhaps the only ticket about reading data incorrectly is the fixes one that deals with multilinestrings and Z.

Comment: Safety is relative. How critical is the application you are using? Only you can make this judgement.

Comment: @user30184, thanks for sneaking in your very useful answer before this question was declared to not be able to have useful answers. ;)